# absent and present of employees using mysql

Tags: mysql

I Have two tables 
1. user details
2 user attendance stored with 1-present tag

```
Create Table Emp ( 
    Empid int, 
    EmpName Varchar(50) 
); 

Create Table Atten (
    EmpId int, 
    Chechout datetime 
); 

Insert into Emp Values (1,'Emp1'), (2,'Emp2'), (3,'Emp3'); 

Insert into Atten Values (1,'2013/06/11'), (2,'2013/06/11'), (1,'2013/06/12');
```

Now I want  to show both present date and absent date both

```
  ID  EmployeeID    status      Date    
    1        1         P         2015-09-01 22:00:00
    2        2         A          2015-09-02 22:48:00
    3        3         p          2015-09-03 20:48:00  
    1        1         A          2015-09-04 08:00:00
```

I am able to do individual absent records by this query:

```
SELECT m.emp_id     AS `Empid` 
     , d.dt        AS `AbsentDate`,
(CASE WHEN p.punch_status IS NULL
                           THEN 'A'
                           ELSE p.punch_status
                  END 

                  )  s
  FROM ( SELECT DATE(t.added_date) AS dt
           FROM pmc_attendance t
        WHERE date(t.added_date) >= '2018-09-01' 
            AND date(t.added_date) < DATE_ADD( '2018-09-05' ,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
          GROUP BY DATE(t.added_date)
          ORDER BY DATE(t.added_date)
       ) d
 CROSS
  JOIN tbl_admin_users m
  LEFT
  JOIN  pmc_attendance p
    ON date(p.added_date) >= d.dt
   AND date(p.added_date) <  d.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND p.emp_id = m.emp_id
 WHERE p.emp_id IS NULL  and m.emp_id='000838' group by d.dt
 ORDER
    BY m.emp_id
     , d.dt
```

but I want both present absent in single query. any help

Comment: Table structures and some sample data would really help...

Comment: Create Table Emp
( Empid int,
 EmpName Varchar(50)
 );
Create Table Atten
(EmpId int,
 Chechout datetime
 );
Insert into Emp Values
(1,'Emp1'),
(2,'Emp2'),
(3,'Emp3');
Insert into Atten
Values
(1,'2013/06/11'),
(2,'2013/06/11'),
(1,'2013/06/12');

Comment: your data sample and your expected  result don't match ....